# Android start activity in different java package

Tags: java, android, android-intent, package

I'm building an Android application that needs to have customer specific code. Customer specific code needs to be separated from the actual Android product our company supplies.

To do this I tried to create 2 packages:

- com.company.product.activity
- com.company.product.customcode.activity

Both packages contain ExampleActivity. 
I have written a factory that uses reflection to determine of a custom component exists on top of the product class. This works fine.

Using the following code to start the ExampleActivity of product works:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.company.product.activity.ExampleActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Using the following code to start the ExampleActivity of customcode fails:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.company.product.customcode.activity.ExampleActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Error:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.product.customername/com.company.product.customcode.activity.ExampleActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppIndex: The URI host must match the package name and follow the format (android-app://<package_name>/<scheme>/[host_path]). Provided URI: android-app://com.company.product.customcode.activity/http/host/path
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
```

I also tried this code, but then Android gives a Toast that it cannot find the Activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.company.product.customcode.activity", "com.company.product.customcode.activity.ExampleActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="com.company.product.activity.ExampleActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:noHistory="false"
                />

    //Custom implementation of the ExampleActivity
    <activity   android:name="com.company.product.customcode.activity.ExampleActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:noHistory="false"
                />
```

Does anybody have any ideas or tips how to achieve the maingoal: To split custom code from the productcode where activity names might be equal.

Comment: I'm not 100% on that, but it seems to me that you should look into product flavors. It's backed right into the build tools and it's very easy to have different code for different versions. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors

Comment: "Using the following code to start the ExampleActivity of customcode fails." What error you are getting when you have used this?

Comment: @Raghavendra see the code block right under the code in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you missed here. I have tried this and it worked.

I have created a class MainActivity under package **com.sample.so_sample.activities**

and another MainActivity under package **com.sample.so_sample1.test.activities**

My manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.so_sample">

 <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sample.so_sample1.test.activities.MainActivity">
        </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

and my call to navigate in **com.sample.so_sample.activities.MainActivity** is

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, com.sample.so_sample1.test.activities.MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for testing, I have created a new application and it works indeed... now its time to start debugging till I know why it doesn't work in my main-app.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in the code.I had tried the same,it seems no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Differen package names is the right way, it has to work fine, seem like problem is out of this code.

Your code can be in any java packages, you need just specify fully qulified name of activity in manifest. Android package name it's just a unique app id string.
instead of:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.company.product.customcode.activity", "com.company.product.customcode.activity.ExampleActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("YOUR PACKAGE NAME IN MANIFEST", "com.company.product.customcode.activity.ExampleActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this question. 
It seemed by further investigation that the Activity crashed because of some auto-generated code that was added while copy-pasting....
It seemed like a crash before the Activity was loaded, but this apparently was not the case.

Thank you all for you're answers, they were very useful!